# Reg command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a simple batch file with following line of codes in it but as soon as I trigger this batch file (either running it from command prompt or double clicking on it), it continuously runs. Like forever.
I am just trying to modify existing key in registry using batch file to some specific value.

```
reg add "hkcu\control panel\desktop" /v ForegroundLockTimeout /d "0x30d40" /f /t REG_DWORD

exit
```

In order to stop execution when I am giving interrupt (Cntrl + C) it asks whether it should terminate execution of this batch file or not..

Can someone help to understand what is wrong with this code?
I think it should stop execution once it updates registry key but that is not happening. It continuously prints line# 1 on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called the batch file `reg.bat` right?

Try `regfile.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, this works for me:

```
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v ForegroundLockTimeout /t REG_DWORD /d "0x30d40" /f
```

It returns:

```
The Operation completed successfully.
```

Obviously try saving that to your bat file and then run the batfile as usual.